# How to define MAM archiving time

Tags: ejabberd

Is it possible to define how long the messages are stored in the MAM archive?

Prosody xmmp server uses mam_module option "archive_expires_after".

Is this ejabberd configuration equivalent?

`mod_mam: cache_life_time: 24 # Store for 1 day`